# sshpass not working in shell script while giving username and password in varibales

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, command-substitution

I am using this below script and i am getting this error `-p: command not found`

Code:

```
echo "Enter the server name"
read -s server
echo "Enter the Remote Username"
read -s Rem_user
echo "Enter the Remote Password"
read -s rmtpasswrd
output=sshpass -p ${rmtpasswrd} ssh ${Rem_user}@${server} -T 'df -h;'
echo $output
```

Please let me know what is the error in the script.

Comment: Why prompt the user for a password when `ssh` can do the same?

Comment: You are also not using a command substitution as is necessary to capture the output of another command.

Comment: Can you give me an example please on ssh prompt password @chepner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a command substitution to run `ssh` and capture its output.

```
output=$(ssh "${Rem_user}@${server}" 'df -h')
```

There is no reason to use `sshpass` if you are going to prompt the user for a password. `ssh` already does that (and more securely than you can).